# どのような場合にコミュニティ Wiki としての投稿が有効ですか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, コミュニティwiki

信用度が10以上の場合は「コミュニティWiki」での回答が可能なようですが、未だに利用されている例をメタ以外で見たことがありません。
どのような質問を想定してこの機能が作られたのですか？

Answer (score 5):

基本的に、質問より回答をコミュニティWikiにするケースが多いです。

例えば、同じ問題がいろんな形で質問として投稿されることがあります。誰かが「この問題にちゃんとした回答を用意して、今後聞かれたらその回答を参照してもらえばいいことにしましょう」と考えて、将来にわたってベストアンサーの地位を保てるような回答をコミュニティWikiとして投稿します。そうすると、信用度が少なくても、多くのユーザーが編集できるようになります。

ネットワーク上の他のサイトでは、主にメタで利用していますが、メインでも上記のケースなど、複数の人が管理する投稿であれば、コミュニティWikiがいいと思います。

Comment: わかりにくかったのでマイナス票を入れましたが[タイトルに “クローズ” と含まれた質問の対処](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1677/4410)で理解出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

Wikiにはタグに関するものと回答に関するものがありますが、

回答に関するものから意見を述べさせていただきます。

私は、次のような場合にWiki回答が有効だと考えています。
主観的な回答が必要でリスト形式になってしまうが、中立的立場が保てると判断できる場合

理由としては、

- 回答が一つにまとまっている
- 複数の回答による人気投票にならずに済む (Wikiは個人の信用度に影響することが無いため)

以上の点から、全員にとってより良い回答となることが期待できます。
もちろん、比較しない、不確定な欠点を表記しないなどの配慮は必要かと思います。

続いて、タグwikiについてです。

ここで、タグwikiという表現を勝手ながらタグ詳細とさせてください。
理由は素晴らしいコーダーがWikipediaを巡回するプログラムを書かれて
タグにWikiが追加される日が来ると信じているからです。

タグ詳細については、
もちろんタグについての説明が必要でしょうがWikipediaを真似る必要はないと思います。
例えば、人気の質問、よくある質問などのサイト内のリンクがいいのかと思います。